# I am Lebanese and a resident in the UAE. Can I travel from the UAE to Lebanon with a transit in Doha, Qatar and a passport less then 6 months?

Tags: transit, passports, doha, lebanese-citizens

- Lebanese passport
- Going to Lebanon
- From the UAE
- Passport less then 6 months
- Layover in Qatar

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you travel with a single ticket, there should be no problem. If you have separate tickets you need to enter Qatar which may require a visa.

Entering Lebanon with a Lebanese passport should be no problem.

A Timatic search for Qarar transit via [the Emirates site](https://www.emirates.com/il/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/) says:

> Passengers transiting through Doha (DOH) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

There's no mention of passport validity. From atories I heard of transit in Qatar, if you don't go thorough immigration your passport isn't checked at any time.